# Formula field not working - Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, DateTime, received Date

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field, custom-field, datetime

I wrote the following formula to calculate number of hours (monday-friday 9am to 5pm) between two dates:

```
(
  5 * (
    FLOOR(( Closed__c - Opened__c ) / 7) +
    MIN(1, MOD( Closed__c - Opened__c, 7 ))
  )
  - MIN(
    1,
    IF(
      VALUE(TEXT(Closed__c)) - VALUE(TEXT(Closed__c)) + (8 / 24) > 0.708333333333333,
      IF(
        MOD(Closed__c - DATE(1900, 1, 1), 1) > 0.708333333333333,
        2,
        IF(MOD(Closed__c - DATE(1900, 1, 1), 1) < 0.375, 0, 1)
      ),
      IF(
        VALUE(TEXT(Opened__c)) - VALUE(TEXT(Opened__c)) + (8 / 24) < 0.375,
        IF(
          MOD(Opened__c - DATE(1900, 1, 1), 1) < 0.375,
          0,
          IF(MOD(Opened__c - DATE(1900, 1, 1), 1) > 0.708333333333333, 2, 1)
        ),
        1
      )
    )
  )
) * 8
```

I gives me the following syntax error on line 11:

```
Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, DateTime, received Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are pretty high that `Closed__c` and `Opened__c` are *datetimes* and not *dates*.

We can use + and minus between two datetimes, or between two dates, but not between a date and a datetime (which is what it appears that the error is complaining about).

You'll need to convert one to the other so that both of the operands are of the same type. Given that it appears you're trying to find hours here (what with the `MOD(x, 1)`, it probably makes the most sense to change `DATE(1900, 1, 1)` into the equivalent datetime using `DATETIMEVALUE()` (read the documentation for hints on how to use it).

Alternatively, you may want to skip working with Datetimes and just use the time component (since it appears that you're tossing the date portion out entirely). `TIMEVALUE()` may be more appropriate.